# Probability of $k$ vectors being linearly independant

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, vector-spaces

Let $v_1, \ldots v_k \in \mathbb{F}_2^n, k\leq n$ be randomly chosen vektors. How can i prove that the chance, that all of them are linearly independant is given with the formula

$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-2^{i-n}\right)$

My approach would be the following:

The first factor is the probability that the first two vectors in $ v_1, \ldots, v_j $ are linearly independent. The second factor is the probability that the third is linearly independent of the other two, provided that the previous vectors were already linearly independent of one another and so on for all $ k $ vectors.

I feel like this is not really a proof. How can i improve my argument?

Comment: the $i$"th factor is the probability that the $i$'th vector isn't in the span of the previous ones conditioned to the first $i-1$ vectors being LI